# How to get social activities interpreter class working in Liferay

Tags: java, xml, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to make an interpreter class for my blog entries in liferay to display them like I want them. The blog entries appears in a portlet - hook named so-activities-hook. I have followed these steps: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding+Social+Activity+Tracking+to+a+Portlet and I am using SocialActivityLocalServiceUtil.addActivity().

But it just wont work.. It all compiles and shows up in the activities-hook but not interpreted by my class as I want it displayed.. It just adds an activity through the interpreter class in the hook (not with my title, link and body) :/

Anyone who could find what I have done wrong in my code?

```
public class ActivityFeed extends MVCPortlet {

public  void doView (RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws PortletException, IOException 
{


    include("/html/activityfeed/view.jsp",renderRequest,renderResponse);

}


public void sendNewMessage(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response){

    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

    long userId = themeDisplay.getUserId();
    long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();

    try {
        SocialActivityLocalServiceUtil.addActivity(userId, groupId, BlogsEntry.class.getName(), 14341, 2, "{\"title\":\"Bam\"}", 0);
    } catch (PortalException | SystemException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    SocialActivity sa = SocialActivityLocalServiceUtil.createSocialActivity(14341);

MessageInterpreter mi = new MessageInterpreter();

    SocialActivityInterpreterLocalServiceUtil.addActivityInterpreter(mi); 

    try {
        mi.doInterpret(sa, themeDisplay);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

And the interpreter class:

```
public class MessageInterpreter extends SOSocialActivityInterpreter {

@Override
public String[] getClassNames() {
    return _CLASS_NAMES;
}

@Override
protected SocialActivityFeedEntry doInterpret(
        SocialActivity activity, ThemeDisplay themeDisplay)
    throws Exception {

    String link = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    String title = "Interpreter Title";
    String body = "<div class=\"activity-body\"><div class=\"title\"><span><img class=\"icon\" src=\""></span><span>New message</span></div><div class=\"blogs-page-content\">";

    return new SocialActivityFeedEntry(link, title, body);
}

private static final String[] _CLASS_NAMES = {BlogsEntry.class.getName()};
```

}

I allso have the tags for interpreter class in my liferay-portlet.xml:

```
<liferay-portlet-app>
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>activity-feed</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <social-activity-interpreter-class>com.test.MessageInterpreter</social-activity-interpreter-class>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>
        /js/main.js
    </footer-portlet-javascript>
    <css-class-wrapper>activity-feed-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>guest</role-name>
    <role-link>Guest</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    <role-link>Power User</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <role-link>User</role-link>
</role-mapper>
```

I am using Liferay 6.2 and tomcat 7

Allso I have realy realy tried to search the internet for help but have not find any solution to this problem.. Thank you